# x86 - Number of registers vs number of reserved bits

Tags: assembly, x86, machine-instruction

I am new to assembly and my question is:

If a machine has, for example, n registers. How many bits need to be reserved in the assembly instruction to address each of the n registers? 
And by how much could a functional split reduce the bits needed?

Comment: This sounds like homework, especially the last part. If you can't figure out _that_ one, you really need a piece of paper and sit down to think.

Comment: Note that the x86 ISA doesn't use fixed-size instructions. If you're interested in the details of instruction encoding on the x86, read the [Intel software developer's manual](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html) (the section about ModR/M bytes might be of particular interest to you).

Comment: @DarkDust I am just following a textbook and I am wondering how they get to the least number of bits needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no universal answer to this. Obviously you would need at *most* enough bits to store the number of registers. So if you have 12 registers, you'd need 4 bits (2^4 == 16).

But an instruction set could treat some registers in different ways (for example, have instructions that implicitly addresses only a specific register; see `LOOP` for x86). So a CPU could have 9 registers, but since one can only be accessed with specialized instruction you'd only need 3 bits to address the remaining 8. Also, some instructions can allow only a certain subset of registers, thus also reducing the amount of bits required to address them (say, an instruction only allows to operate on registers 0–3).

And to make it even more complicated, there's [register windows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Register_window) which only make a subset of the physical registers available to the instruction set.

Comment: `loop` or `movsb` would be a better example.  `rep` isn't a stand-alone instruction, and can only apply to a few other insns.  What did you mean by saying some opcodes can only address limited registers?  Are you talking about 64bit mode without a REX prefix?  I can't think of an example where you have a limited choice of register that's encoded in fewer bits than normal.  (Other than 16-bit addressing modes, and that `esp/rsp` can't be an index register in 32/64bit addressing modes.)

Comment: @PeterCordes: You're right, `loop` is a much better example. Have updated my answer. Regarding the limited registers: my answer is about generic (thus also theoretic) CPU designs, though I faintly remembered that there was were instructions with such limitations in 8086 and/or M68000; trying to find those, it seems I was wrong. The x86 family doesn't use register windows either, BTW.

Comment: You should take out the "some x86 opcodes do this", because it's wrong.  The rest of your answer is good (and I wasn't the downvoter), and it's clear you're not talking about x86 in the rest of it.  If you're looking for examples, some architecture (ARM, IIRC, but I'm not sure) has instructions that use two registers, and the 2nd instruction is implicitly the odd/even partner of the explicit reg (toggle the low bit, rather than adding 1).  For special regs: MIPS has 32 GP registers plus HI and LO to hold the result of a full-multiply (32x32b => 64b), good example for your 8+1.